# Probe request from user devices broadcasting what frequency?

Tags: ieee-802.11

I have been researching whether a device with a wifi interface sends out signals in the RF spectrum. I have been a little here and there, and I understand that wifi devices uses active and passive scanning to detect beacons sent by a router. In other words, wifi devices sends out probe request and waits for probe responses from the access points.

My question is simply if these probe requests are sent as radio waves in the same frequency range as the wifi. So if my laptop has wifi turned on, and it sends probe requests to a router that has 2.4GHz network, will these probe request be in that range?

I appreciate all the help I can get. I have sort of found out a lot, but not this specifically. I am not a professional so it is hard for me to find exactly this.
Thank you!
Best regards

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

> So if my laptop has wifi turned on, and it sends probe requests to a router that has 2.4GHz network, will these probe request be in that range?

Of course. The probe requests are meant for the access point , which is listening to a specific channel. Typically that’s channel 1, 6, or 11.